# Jenkins/Build workflow: Provide result of one parallel executed job to multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-workflow

Try to implement following workflow in Jenkins: A trigger starts the parallel jobs A, B, C and D. As soon as A, B and C finish the job X should start and the same for job Y, it should start after C and D.

Workflow sketch:

```
          -> A -> 
 Trigger  -> B -> X -> Result 1
          -> C =>
          -> D -> Y -> Result 2
```

I started with the [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) but I have no idea how to design the workflow without starting C twice:

```
parallel (
  { 
     Xpre = parallel ([
        first:  { a = build("TGZ", subjob: "T1") },
        second: { b = build("TGZ", subjob: "T2") },
        third:  { c = build("TGZ", subjob: "T3") }
     ])

     build("TGZ", subjob: "X")
  },
  {
     Ypre = parallel ([
        third2:  { c2 = build("TGZ", subjob: "T3") },
        fourth:  { d = build("TGZ", subjob: "T4") }
     ])

     build("TGZ", subjob: "Y")
  }
)
```

Any clue on how to design this workflow without running C twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, though still awkward, in the newer [Workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin):

`def aDone = false
def bDone = false
def cDone = false
def dDone = false
parallel a: {
  runA()
  aDone = true
}, b: {
  runb()
  bDone = true
}, c: {
  runC()
  cDone = true
}, d: {
  runD()
  dDone = true
}, x: {
  waitUntil {aDone && bDone && cDone}
  runX()
}, y: {
  waitUntil {cDone && dDone}
  runY()
}`

[JENKINS-27127](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27127) discusses possible enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

build flow won't help here, as you have two jobs (X and Y) that are waiting for C to complete, so not a "linear" (not sure this is the adequate terminology) dependency tree, but a complex graph. You're looking for a more complex *asynchronous* model that is not (yet) implemented by build-flow. Maybe could be introduced later, but low priority at this stage of development :

```
   parallel( [
        a:  { build("TGZ", subjob: "T1") },
        b: { build("TGZ", subjob: "T2") },
        c:  { build("TGZ", subjob: "T3") }
     ])
   .on( jobs[a].completed && jobs[b].completed && jobs[c].completed ) { build(x) } 
   .on( jobs[c].completed && jobs[d].completed ) { build(y) }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer Nicolas! Should I open a new ticket in JIRA for the enhancement?